# How to add the sequential numbers if certain condition met in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sequential

Need to increase the sequential numbers if certain condition is met or else need to hold the previous number.

Original_dataset:

| ID | Name | Status | Cluster | Gap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | 1 | 15 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 1 | 35 |
| 1 | C | 1 | 1 | 03 |
| 2 | B | 0 | 1 | 26 |
| 2 | C | 0 | 1 | 16 |
| 3 | A | 1 | 1 | 65 |
| 3 | C | 0 | 1 | 89 |
| 3 | F | 0 | 1 | 19 |

Required_Dataset:

| ID | Name | Status | Cluster | Gap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | 1 | 15 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 2 | 35 |
| 1 | C | 1 | 3 | 03 |
| 2 | B | 0 | 1 | 26 |
| 2 | C | 0 | 1 | 16 |
| 3 | A | 1 | 1 | 65 |
| 3 | C | 0 | 2 | 89 |
| 3 | F | 0 | 2 | 19 |

Conditions:

1. For first occurrence of ID, the cluster should be 1.
2. If status = 1 or Gap > 28, then cluster needs to increase by 1 based on patient ID (see row 1-C and 2-B --- as ID changes, the Cluster remains 1 as it is the first occurrence of the particular ID).
3. If the condition is not satisfied, it needs to hold the previous cluster number. (Can refer the final row).

The code which I have tried is:

```
Original_dataset.loc[((new_df4['gap'] > 28) | (Original_dataset['status'] == 1)),'Cluster'] = Original_dataset['Cluster'] + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

First set `1` if greater GAP like `28` or if `Status` is `1` or first duplicated value of `ID` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), then use lambda function with [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) and [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html)

```
m = df['Gap'].gt(28)
m1 = df['Status'].eq(1)
m2 = ~df['ID'].duplicated()

df.loc[m | m1 | m2, 'Cluster1'] = 1

f = lambda x: x.cumsum().ffill(downcast='int')
df['Cluster1'] = df.groupby('ID')['Cluster1'].transform(f)
print (df)
   ID Name  Status  Cluster  Gap  Cluster1
0   1    A       0        1   15         1
1   1    B       1        1   35         2
2   1    C       1        1    3         3
3   2    B       0        1   26         1
4   2    C       0        1   16         1
5   3    A       1        1   65         1
6   3    C       0        1   89         2
7   3    F       0        1   19         2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mask based on 3 conditions, and a simple [`groupby.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
# is Gap≥28 OR Status==1 OR first ID ?
m = df['Gap'].ge(28) | df['Status'].eq(1) | ~df['ID'].duplicated()

# then increment count per group
df['Cluster'] = m.groupby(df['ID']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   ID Name  Status  Cluster  Gap
0   1    A       0        1   15
1   1    B       1        2   35
2   1    C       1        3    3
3   2    B       0        1   26
4   2    C       0        1   16
5   3    A       1        1   65
6   3    C       0        2   89
7   3    F       0        2   19
```